# How to prove certain relation on $J6$ is partial order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $R$ be the relation on $J6$ defined by $R =\{ (a, b) \in J6 \times  J6\,\, | \,\,a = b \text{ or } a + 3 \leq b \}.$ Prove that R is a partial order relation on $J6$.

So I fully understand that $a=b$ is a partial order relation as it is the identity relation. $a+3\leq b$ however is where I am being stumped.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by $J6$?

Comment: It's just the set (1,2,3,4,5,6)

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Reflexivity:}$It is obvious that $aRa$.(since a=a).

$\textbf{Anti-symmetry:}$ Suppose $aRb$ and $bRa$.Either $a=b$ ( which in that case there is nothing left to prove) or $a+3\leq b$ and $b+3\leq a$. The case $a-b\leq-3$ and $b-a\leq -3$, never happens!

$\textbf{Transitivity:}$ Assume $aRb$ and $bRc$. Note that $a+3\leq b$ and $b+3\leq c$ never occurs is $J6$

(Since $a-b\leq-3$ and $b-c\leq -3$, then $a-c\leq -6$. This is never the case in $J6$.)

So either($a=b$ and $b+3\leq 3b$) or ($a+3\leq b$ and $b=c$) or (a=b=c). In all these cases, conclusion is that $aRc$.